# How to read properties file from different location in JAVA

Tags: java

I have sourcehandler.java class which has the code

```
public class SourceHandler {
  String PrpPath = null;
  Properties prop = null;

 public Properties loadConfigProperties() {

try {

    System.out.println("Propertiess " +PrpPath );
    InputStream in =new FileInputStream(new File(PrpPath ));
    prop.load(in);

} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
return prop;
}
```

and main method in a different class,

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException,
                                              Exception {
    try {

        SourceHandler conf = new SourceHandler();

        conf.setProperties("C:/config.properties");

        Properties p = conf.loadConfigProperties();

        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (DOMException dome) {
        // TODO: Add catch code
        dome.printStackTrace();
     }
```

Now, if i run the code , it shows null pointer exception at line ,   `prop.load(in);`

stack trace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at DecryptEncryptSource.SourceHandler.loadConfigProperties(SourceHandler.java:98)
>       at DecryptEncryptSource.SourceHandler.updateCofigDestn(SourceHandler.java:151)
>       at DecryptEncryptSource.MainClass.main(MainClass.java:27)

Comment: Could you add the exact path `String` you are using ?

Comment: yes Berger, that is the exact path " C:\config.properties'' passed from main method i could print also thru sop..

Comment: Show us how you pass it from the `main` method. That is crucial.

Comment: I Have a variable 'Properties' in Source handler class and using accessor setter method i am setting the value of path of proprties file from public static void main(String[] args) throws  try {
            SourceHandler conf = new SourceHandler();

           conf.setProperties(" C:\\config.properties");
            
            conf.updateCofigDestn();
            
            System.out.println("Done");

        } catch (DOMException dome) {
            // TODO: Add catch code
            dome.printStackTrace();

        } 
        }

Comment: Did you copy and paste the `main`-code in your comment? Your path starts with a blank, that would match the error-message, since absolute paths should start with a drive-letter, not a blank.

Comment: @piet the above is main code , i had made changes , and it starts with drive-letter now , its java.lang.NullPointerException at line      prop.load(in); please suggest any ideas

Answer (score 0):

First of all,

```
InputStream in =new FileInputStream(new File(Properties));
```

should better read

```
InputStream in =new FileInputStream(new File(propertyFileName));
```

to avoid any ambiguity; and then:

- Are you sure that there is really a file named `C:\config.properties`
- Probably you need either escaping: `C:\\config.properties`; or you try `C:/config.properties`

Regarding the update; you have this line:

```
Properties prop = null;
```

and further down:

```
prop.load(in);
```

And you are surprised that you get a NPE? Really? Hint: look into your code and **create** that Property object using the file path; instead of just calling a method on a null object.

And the real answer is read this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) over and over again.

(and for those who wonder why I didn't close out as duplicate ... I can't any more, because I already close-requested on another reason )

Comment: I have the file in that path C:\\config.properties , now at line ,  prop.load(in); it throws java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: You are welcome. In case you are "happy" .. please consider accepting my answer. Now, or when you are sure that you will be around tomorrow; tomorrow would be fine, too ;-)